# Android - AChartEngine Doughnut Shaped Pie Chart

Tags: android, android-layout, charts, achartengine

I need to create a **doughnut shaped Pie Chart**, exactly as below example:

[image]

Maybe some people will ask why I said a **Pie Chart** instead of **Doughnut Chart**. I tried using Doughnut Chart, but the legend doesn't give me the information I need. It gave me *category titles* instead of *color definition* of each area in the chart, just like below image:

[image]

See the legend above? That is not what I want. Instead, I need the legend to be like the one in Pie Chart:

[image]

But Pie Chart has no hole in the center. How to make a doughnut shaped Pie Chart?

Comment: Did you ever get the desired solution? If it's a public library, kindly link it in your reply, I am also in need of such a library.